# What are the parameters for constructor of class cl_DBHandler which extends SQLiteOpenHelper in android?

Tags: android, database, service

i have created class `cl_DBHandler`which extends  `SQLiteOpenHelper`. and i have created class  `my_srvc`which extends `service`.  i have intialise object `m_DBHandler`of class `cl_DBHandler`in service but while initialization object i have to pass parameters to `cl_DBHandler(context, name, factory, version)`, i am not getting exactly what to pass in this.
i have pass like this `cl_DBHandler(getappcontext(),"databasename.sqlite",null,1)`

2nd thing: i am calling one function from class with help of `m_DBHandler object` but i am getting value null of `object m_DBHandler` at every call though i have intialise that `object in service`.can anyone tell me or guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following constructor for your cl_DBHandler class

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public cl_DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

In your service or activity:

```
cl_DBHandler m_DBHandler = new cl_DBHandler(this);
```

Then open your database:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
try {
        db = m_DBHandler.getWritableDatabase();

    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        db = m_DBHandler.getReadableDatabase();
    }
// do anything you like for example:
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strQuery, null);
```

Comment: hi, in_DBHnadler object intialisation is it sufficient to pass only this to function cl_DBHandler?its sounds error

Comment: Actually i have done it already but i am getting null-pointer exception at m_Handler.

Comment: in cl_DBHandler i have opened database and created obj for get getreadabledatabase() n writable as well.. so is it necessary to open database again seperatly?

Comment: no it is opened after getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase

Comment: yeah it is opened after getWritableDatabase..ok should i tell you the flow in detail??

Comment: have you implemented onCreate function correctly? please explain more.

Comment: its done.i just initialize m_Handler in my activity from which i called that function..:)